# Titles in LaTeX

Tags: titles

I would like to know how to make this type of titles in LaTeX: 
[image]

Like this one too
[image]

I think it is with the package titling but I'm not to familiar with it. 
Appreciate the help.

Comment: That's apples and oranges. Basically, your question is how to get text on the page. That would be covered in every introduction.

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280/37907 helps